# Is it possible to include the comment in a comment by using JS or other PL?

Tags: javascript, html, comments

Is it possible to include the comment in a comment by using any other languages? The only condition is that I'am building static website, so we need to avoid using PHP.

I know that this has been asked already, and [it is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298802/is-it-possible-to-comment-comments). The answer states that I need to use version control, but that answer is on the year 2011. This question is also [the same here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12998915/commenting-a-commented-markup-nested-comments) and it clearly says it is not possible in HTML, but the answer is on the year 2012. Are there any other methods out there? It's almost 2015, maybe I can achieve it by using JS?

I would like to use that in a situation where I can easily make the sources online (if I have the internet) and offline (If I don't have internet).

**Sample code:**

```
<!-- Offline Sources -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/javapreloadjs-0.4.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- preloadjs-0.4.1.min.js -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/bitmapdata-1.0.2.min.js"></script>
<!-- bitmapdata-1.0.2.min.js -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/vector3d-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
<!-- vector3d-1.2.0.min.js -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/stats.js"></script>
<!-- stats.min.js -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/break-image.js"></script>
<!-- Break Image end -->



<!-- Online Sources -->

<!--

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jsrun.it/assets/o/w/w/d/owwdC"></script>
<!-- preloadjs-0.4.1.min.js -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jsrun.it/assets/t/C/4/c/tC4cT"></script>
<!-- bitmapdata-1.0.2.min.js -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jsrun.it/assets/i/d/o/F/idoFR"></script>
<!-- vector3d-1.2.0.min.js -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jsrun.it/assets/3/n/9/C/3n9CY"></script>
<!-- stats.min.js -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jsrun.it/assets/j/L/J/z/jLJzs"></script>
<!-- Break Image end -->

-->
```

Notice that this will only comment this code

```
 <!--

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jsrun.it/assets/o/w/w/d/owwdC"></script>
<!-- preloadjs-0.4.1.min.js -->
```

Because the HTML thinks that the first **-->** is the end of a comment.

There are also situation where I'am debugging the code that has lots of comment trying to explain everything and I just want to comment a certain block of codes so I can try something.

Like this

```
<!-- Temporary comment so I can play with this portion of code
<!-- Header part -->
<h1> Sample Header</h1><!-- This is a header -->
<!-- End of Header -->
-->


<!-- Header part -->
<h1>Now I can do anything that I want to this code while leaving a comment of this portion of the code!</h1><!-- This is a header -->
<!-- End of Header -->
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Commenting a commented markup (Nested comments)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12998915/commenting-a-commented-markup-nested-comments)

Comment: Yes, that's why I put that link in my question. That question focuses on using HTML, maybe I can achieve it using other PL?

Comment: No, this is not possible.

Comment: If there is allready an answer to your question why would you ask it again?

Comment: My question is looking for other programming languages, or even library that can comment the comment, while the other question specifically looks for an html-way. I think those are different questions.

Comment: Have you considered a server-side solution? Instead of `your_page.html` make it `your_page.php?mode=offline|online` and write a simple logic in php to output respective script tags.

Comment: @georg, yes! That's a good suggestion! I can use that if I'am building a dynamic website, unfortunately my website and hosting site allows static website only.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you want to do this because one set of conditions should import one thing vs another. I think javascript is the best tool for this anyway, even if you *could* use plain html (which you can't, because comments can't be nested in html).

You can load the set of script dynamically, based on whatever conditions need to be met:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Or you could roll up your own (if you're jQuery-averse) by running an XMLHttpRequest and then executing the script.

Comment: "one set of conditions should import one thing vs another." yes. This is my reason. Thanks gyeh for the support. i'll see if this is the answer that I am looking for.